# jquery mobile disabled text field became enabled because it's cached

Tags: jquery-mobile, caching

I'm making a page were a user can change  it's password in a jquery mobile site.
This is the HTML code:

```html
<div data-dom-cache="false" data-cache="never" data-role="page" class="pages" id="mypage" data-theme="c">
...
<fieldset style="border: solid 1px; padding: 20px;"><legend><strong style="font-size: 14px;">Cambio Password</strong></legend>

     <input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="" size="32" onKeyUp="controllaCampo2(this.id,this.value);" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Old Password">

     <input name="nuovaPassword" type="password" id="nuovaPassword" value="" size="32"  placeholder="New Password" disabled>

     <input name="pass2word"  placeholder="Repeat Password" type="password" id="pass2word" value="" size="32" onChange="controllaPwd();" disabled>
        </fieldset>
...
</div>
```

An ajax checks for the password and if it's correct enables the disabled text fields...and this works correctly, but if I reload the page, the fields that should be disabled are still enabled ...
But I'm unable to remove this caching

Comment: Disable them on `pageshow` programmatically.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yxSfd/